# Select for running total rank based on column values

Tags: sql

I have problem while assigning the Ranks for the below scenarios.In my scenario running total calculated based on the Cnt field.

My sql query should return Rank values like below output. Per page it should accept only 40 rows, so im assigning ranks contain only 40 records. If the running total crossing 40 it should change ranks. For each count 40 it should change the rank values.

It would great help if I can get sql query to return values

```
select f1,f2,sum(f2) over(order by f1) runnign_total
from [dbo].[Sheet1$]
```

OutPut:

```
ID      cnt     Running Total   Rank
1       4       4               1
2       5       9               1
3       4       13              1
4       4       17              1
5       4       21              1
6       5       26              1
7       4       30              1
8       4       34              1
9       4       38              1
10      4       42              2
11      4       46              2
12      4       50              2
13      4       54              2
14      4       58              2
15      4       62              2
16      4       66              2
17      4       70              2
18      4       74              2
19      4       78              2
20      4       82              3
21      4       86              3
22      4       90              3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select f1,f2,sum(f2) over(order by f1) running_total, Floor(sum(f2) over(order by f1) / 40) [rank]
from [dbo].[Sheet1$]
```